# easiest way to add large amounts of images in html using a script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem I could need some help with. I am working on a personal webpage containing large amounts of images and videos. The markup is strictly HTML, and it is styled using CSS. 
I also have one or two Javascripts running. I finished my first page the other day, and just realized that I have to manually add around 20-30 images/videos to each page(I am hoping to build around 10-15 pages), and thought that perhaps there is some script available that can simplify my task to upload all my media content. Keep in mind that all the pages will look the same, so a script would really make things easier.

**Here is what I had in mind. I thought I could create two folders, add all the images and videos to each of them.**

Then use Javascript to iterate through all of the content, adding them into my already built HTML page.

Is this possible? If so, please notify my how I can obtain this solution.

I dont know javascript well enough to code myself so I would appreciate complete solutions.

Here is the HTML

```
<ul>
 <li><iframe width="420" height="345"src=""
</iframe></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="" width=100 height=100/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of Server Side Languages? Like [tag:php]?

Comment: JavaScript by definition does not have access to the filesystem on the server to access your images or videos. You need a server side language, as Madara suggests, to do this

Comment: Javascript can't access the file system, so there is no way for it to know which images to try and load. You can do some tricks with naming conventions but you'll have to hard-code the number of items you're expecting to be there for each page.

Comment: A little ruby script would do the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A javascript only solution would be to use naming conventions and let javascript assume that there should be an item with a specific name.

One example would be:

Rename your files:

`PageName_1.jpg, PageName_2.jpg, PageName_3.jpg, PageName_1.flv, ...`

The downside is that you'll have to define parameters about what types (extensions) of files to look for as well as how many of each type to look for on each page.

```
var files = {'jpg':3, 'flv':1, ...};
var pageName = "PageName";
```

Once you have that set up, you can iterate over the object:

```
for (var ext in files){
    for (var i = 0; i < files[ext]; i++){
        var src = "images/" + pageName + "_" + (i+1) + "." + ext;
        ...
    }
}
```

If you want more than just images, you'll have to create some logic to determine what type of element to generate. The best way to go about this is generally a factory method:

```
function generateElement(src, ext){
    switch(ext){
        case 'jpg':
            ...
        break;
        case 'flv':
            ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Then again, you could just make your life easier and use server-side functionality.

Comment: thanks for the solution. But I have to respond with a dumb question. I dont understand the pageName variable.And why does the filenames require to be called pageName? I understand the sequential numbers, 1,2, 3, etc...

Comment: It's not strictly required, but you'll want to have some sort of separation between pages, I assume

Comment: @Schmiddty , do i need a div with an id or something for it to add the images in my html?

Comment: That's up to you. generally, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, JavaScript cannot access the filesystem so there is no way for it to automatically know what files are available.

Personally, I like to use PHP 5.4's built-in server for this kind of thing. It's easy enough for PHP to `glob()` the files and put them in an HTML page.

Alternatively, you could have a batch script "compile" the list of files for JavaScript to read:

```
dir /B *.png;*.gif;*.jpg > filelist.txt
```

Then you could get the file with AJAX or similar and split it on newlines - each file will be on one line. This way, all you have to do is run the batch script to update the file list for you.